# Joining three table

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I am sure I am missing something stupid but... I have 3 table.. Obviously I'm making up bs here, but play along.  I'm doing this on android, so it's SQLite... No FULL OUTER JOIN, which I believe is what I actually want.

table 1

```
 id type speed, weight, color
------------------------------
|1  car  80mph, 900pds, white
|2  boat 40mph, 400pds, white
|3  car  90mph, 800pds, green
|4  boat 30mph, 750pds, black
```

table 2

```
id, seats, doors
----------------
|1  4,     4
|3  2,     2
```

table 3

```
id  waterDisplaced
------------------
|2  400gal
|4  400gal
```

I am just trying to combine them into one, replacing none existent. And apparently in android sqllite thats harder than it should be.

what I'd want

```
 id type speed, weight, color, seats, doors, waterDisplaced
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|1  car  80mph, 900pds, white, 4,     4,     nul
|2  boat 40mph, 400pds, white, nul,   nul,   400gal
|3  car  90mph, 800pds, green, 2,     2,     nul
|4  boat 30mph, 750pds, black, nul,   nul,   400gal
```

I've tried a waft of left join union right joins, etc.  Honestly, too many remember all of the things I've tried.

Comment: What did you try so far? What's the part that is challenging to you? It seems like the most typical JOIN case.

Comment: Oh man, going through the list is too extensive and I've not saved them all. It refuses to join properly. sometimes I get errors about the mismatched amount of cols, other times it populates but hoses the id numbers.

Comment: This seems like an SQL question, not Kotlin nor Android.  Can you update your question with 3 table structures that shows what the sources that match the table where you show your desired output table.  The answer will be in helping you construct and SQL join query (outer/inner join etc as necessary)

Comment: I will, I tagged it as android and kotlin just because then it kind of specified version etc.

Comment: I hope that clarifies it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very typical case for the `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT
  table1.*,
  table2.*,
  table3.*
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 USING(id)
LEFT JOIN table3 USING(id)
```

Please note I didn't test this code, so it may contain minor problems or may require adapting to sqlite.

Comment: This is real close.  It is just adding 3 id tables. It sorts them all on id 1, but then has id:1 and id:2 with the respective nulls.  I may need to go back and redo my class on db.

Comment: So it appears to be this, but I need to add each individual col from table2 and 3, obviously omitting the id.  
Huge thank man! Its been hella long since I did sql/database, I really do appreciate it!